# Problem with iframe Grafana panel into Power BI

Tags: powerbi, grafana, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Grafana 9.1.2 version on Ubuntu 22.04 operating system. I am trying to achieve embed a panel from the dashboard into the Power BI. I have enabled all the required configurations to make iframe embedding available and it works perfectly fine on an HTML static page. But then I encountered the CORS issue when I integrated Power BI with the Grafana dashboard panel which is also resolved by running Grafana behind a reverse proxy using Nginx.

This was working fine as I have successfully embedded my company website URL in Power BI’s iframe.

This is the Grafana configuration.

```
content_security_policy = true
allow_embedding = true
enabled = true
org_name = Kube Network
org_role = Viewer
hide_version = true
```

This is the Nginx configuration.

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/grafana/abc.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/grafana/def.key;
server_name monitoring.*****.net;
listen 80;
access_log /var/log/nginx/grafana.log;

    location / {

            add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";
            add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
            add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, origin, accept";

            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Not showing any error in Grafana logs nor Nginx logs. But I caught this error in the Power BI web interface in Chrome. Does anyone have any clue what is going on in my scenario?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is Grafana iframed? How is iframe created in the browser? Which CSP headers are configured on PoweBI and Grafana? "I have enabled all the required configurations" so what you configured? Why you don't provide reproducible example?

Comment: @JanGaraj, I have added Grafana configurations as well in my question. The following link [Grafana Panel Sharing](https://akshaybobade777.medium.com/embed-grafana-dashboards-in-your-web-application-17df196dcdec) will be helpful until the sharing panel in Grafana. After that, second video [Panel Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syzA3PZx3qk&ab_channel=BIElite) will be helpful in integrating shareable panel into PowerBI. 

I could not find the CSP configuration in PowerBI desktop and web interface.

Comment: Use browser network console - you can see everything here - all Grafana/PowerBI headers are there + errors. You used "doc" where Grafana 8 is used - it is good idea to follow official doc. Your "doc" used also `auth.anonymous`, but you didn't. Why you enabled `content_security_policy`? It really looks like you are guessing everything and don't have idea what are you doing :-(

Comment: @JanGaraj, you are right, I am frustrated and guessing everything. I will follow your suggestion and get back to this thread.

Comment: You need `sandbox="allow-same-origin"` on the iframe.  Read doc about sandbox parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many problems, but one obvious:

```
add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
```

See doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

> In requests with credentials, it is treated as the literal header name "*" without special semantics.

So you allowed only URL `'*'`, not any URL (wildchar URL). That doesn't make sense. Allow your origin explicitly. Keep in mind `Origin` != `URL`. See Origin definition https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

Comment: I read this document and I am using the wildcard URL correctly according to its explanation because I have enabled anonymous access to my panel. If I use an explicit URL of origin then the CORD error popup.